# Не отображается background картинка в PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt, pixmap

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Could not create pixmap from :\newPrefix\1646027878_52-kartinkin-net-p-kartinki-o-sporte-58.jpg

Что делать? Из-за неё не отображается `background`-картинка.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно встречался с такой проблемой и даже задавал вопрос на этом сайте, он кстати вот он [Мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492181/pyqt5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0).
Я могу передать его и сюда:
из **AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins** надо скопировать папку из плагинов imageformats и вставить её в главную папку питона: **AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39**. У вас питон может быть другой.