# PyQt5 не отображается картинка

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Когда я начинаю вставлять изображение в qt designer, оно отображается, но при выполнении кода PyQt просто не видит и не выводит его. Не подскажите что делать?

resource.qrc:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

mydesign.py:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Qt designer:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение с выполнением кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт файла дизайна
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: В случаи питона нужно еще файл ресурсов сгенерировать и, вроде бы, его еще импортировать

Comment: Aix Play, пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставляйте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.  Опубликуйте модуль `mydesign.py` и файл с ресурсами `.qrc` , если он у вас есть. Также расскажите о путях где у вас расположены модули и ресурсы или изображения.

Comment: Aix Play, пожалуйста, прочтите мой комментарий, опубликованный выше. И попробуйте запустить ваше приложение в консоли/терминале/CMD, зайдите в каталог где у вас все лежит `....\venv` и запустите  `python main.py` и расскажите что у вас получилось.

Comment: Он вывел ошибку - qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: Aix Play, полистайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt4%5D+or+%5Bpyqt%5D+or+%5Bpyqt5%5D+or+%5Bpyside2%5D+or+%5Bpyqt6%5D+or+%5Bqt%5D+or+%5Bpyside6%5D+or+%5Bqt-designer%5D+Could+not+find+the+Qt+platform+plugin по-моему проблема такой ошибки уже обсуждалась не один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас должен был появиться файл с рекурсами `.qrc`, пусть будет `resources.qrc`

Теперь нужно его скомпилировать в модуль на питоне через команду в консоли:

```
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py
```

И добавьте импорт перед импортом `from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow`:

```
import resources
```

[Источник](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qresource-system/)

---

**PS.**

Файл `pyrcc5` устанавливается вместе с `PyQt5` и находится в папке питона `\Scripts`. Например:

```
C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

Путь к этой папке в переменных путях `PATH` должен быть, тогда `pyrcc5` будет доступен по имени. Иначе, нужно или добавить эту папку в `PATH`, или запускать, указывая полный путь.

---

**PPS.**

Повторил проект из вопроса:

**mydesign.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>23</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>561</width>
      <height>381</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap resource="resources.qrc">:/newPrefix/input.jpg</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**resources.qrc**

```xml
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>input.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, в папке проекта в консоли выполнил команды:

Генерация формы:

```
pyuic5 -x mydesign.ui -o mydesign.py
```

Компиляция ресурсов:

```
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

Папка проекта теперь имеет такие файлы (кст, если удалить `input.jpg`, то при запуске скрипта картинка будет, т.к. она уже в `resources_rc.py`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**mydesign.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mydesign.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 221, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(23)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 561, 381))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/newPrefix/input.jpg"))
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
import resources_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Кусочек resources_rc.py**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт файла дизайна
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

При запуске картинка из ресурсов подтягивается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема в том что я это и сделал. Он всё равно выполняет код без изображения.

Comment: У вас есть скомпилированной файл ресурсов? И вы его импортируете?

Comment: Да, он у меня есть, это видно на скрине в PyCharm в файлах.

Comment: То, что у вас он есть я не отрицаю. Я cпросил про скопилированный, который получается через команду `pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py`. Наверное, это `resource_rc.py`. Вы его импортировали до `from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow`?

Comment: @AixPlay, повторил создание проекта через Designer, добавил файл ресурсов, из ui сгенерировал py, потом сгенерировал файл ресурсов - работает. Единственное, я указывал `resources_rc.py`, т.к. после `PyQt5.uic.pyuic` в файле `mydesign.py` был импорт `import resources_rc`

Comment: @gli9red, даже после ваших предложенных действий, картинка не отображается. Проблема возможно в том, что у меня 6 interpreter'ов питона.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена по другому из **AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins** надо было скопировать папку из плагинов **imageformats** и вставить её в главную папку питона: **AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39**

Comment: Интересно, а переустановка `PyQt5` помогла бы? `pip uninstall PyQt5` + `pip install PyQt5`

Comment: Да, я так и сделал удалил все версии питона кроме **python3.9** и переустановил **PyQt5**. Когда было много версии питона и я пробовал переустанавливать **PyQt5** это не помогало.

Comment: Мб, не у всех питонов сделали переустановку

Comment: @gli9red, да, не у всех, я просто удалил все питоны, кроме **python 3.9**